# Why am I getting "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'X'" errors, on a hard-coded value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
INSERT INTO DDA_MatchStrings 
(Unit, FamilyID, AccountNumber, MatchType,  MatchString, SnapshotDate,  IgnoreRecord,   Merged)
SELECT 
 Unit, FamilyID, AccountNumber, 'EMAIL',    MatchString, @SnapshotDate, 0,              0
FROM DDA_MatchStrings_temp AS tms 
WHERE tms.MatchString IN 
    (SELECT tms.MatchString FROM DDA_MatchStrings_temp AS tms
    GROUP BY tms.MatchString
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT unit) > 1)
ORDER BY tms.MatchString
```

I added indentation to the field references for visual observation.

This statement is in a stored procedure, but when the SP gets to this point, it is giving the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IgnoreRecord', table
>   'Db.dbo.TableX'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails.

I know what this error means.  I'm not new to T-SQL.  However, I'm completely baffled why it's giving me this error?  The value isn't null.  It's a hardcoded `0`.  FYI, the field in question is a `tinyint`.  It should accept this value.  Also, this statement is also in other stored procedures (with only a different value in the `MatchType` field.

What might cause this error?

**UPDATE**

I've chosen to answer my own question, rather than delete it.  This is a good case where not paying attention to db schemas has caused problems.  It's worth updating as a reference that you should always pay attention to your SQL object definitions and which schemas are provided when executing code.  I hate to be the one making a mistake, but hopefully others will learn from my error.

Comment: My guess is that the select statement is returning zero records (i.e. all nulls) and that column is the only one that cares.  Even though you have a hard-coded value `0`, the row(s) will still either exist or not exist based on your where clause.

Comment: There could also be a trigger on the table that would change a 0 to null?

Comment: FYI, create this table.  There are no triggers.  The filed is defined as `[IgnoreRecord] [tinyint] NOT NULL`.

Comment: Can you run the SELECT statement on it's own and see if there are any NULL values in the column it's referring to? Just realised it's a proc. Can you execute it manually and expose the SELECT statement when you run it? If there are no triggers, the computer does not lie and there must be a NULL :)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how this is possible. Either what is posted is not the query responsible, or there is a trigger altering the results being inserted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok... I feel a bit stupid but I might as well answer this for posterity.

The issue is not with the insert statement, or my script... it relates to schemas. The definition of the SP is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DDA_Generate_PotentialDuplicate_Emails
```

Apparently, at some point I defined it as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DDA_Generate_PotentialDuplicate_Emails
```

This is the first time where I've worked with a corporate db where, by default, the associated schema was the user's login and not dbo.

So... when I changed my execution code from:

```
EXEC DDA_Generate_PotentialDuplicate_Emails
```

to

```
EXEC dbo.DDA_Generate_PotentialDuplicate_Emails
```

Everything started to work properly because I was running the proper version of the stored procedure. :P